# What is an appropriate training set size for text classification (Sentiment analysis)

Tags: nlp, nltk

I just wanted to understand (from your experience), that if I have to create a sentiment analysis classification model (using NLTK), what would be a good training data size. For instance if my training data is going to contain tweets, and I intend to classify them as positive,negative and neutral, how many tweets each should I ideally have per category to get a reasonable model working?

I understand that there are many parameters like quality of data, but if one has to get started what might be  a good number.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really hard question to answer for people who are not familiar with the exact data, its labelling and the application you want to use it for. But as a ballpark estimate, I would say start with 1,000 examples of each and go from there.